# Cannot get request headers on REST server

Tags: php, slim

Im using Slim Framework as an API. Im making a GET request to it. But I cannot get the headers. My PHP file looks like:

```
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    $app = new Slim();
    $app->get('/project/:id', add_authorize(), 'getProject');
    $app->run();
    function getProject($project_title) {
        //connect to database and return project details
    }

    function add_authorize() {
        return function (){
        $app = Slim::getInstance();     
        $charset = $app->request->headers->get('ACCEPT_CHARSET');
        };
    }
```

I get the response:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Slim::$request in C:\wamp\www\server\device_api\index.php on line 23
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  248528  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0240  860056  Slim->run( )    ..\index.php:9
3   0.0240  878816  Slim_Route->dispatch( ) ..\Slim.php:1052
4   0.0240  878864  call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\server\device_api\Slim\Route.php:387} ( )   ..\Route.php:387
5   0.0240  878944  {closure:C:\wamp\www\server\device_api\index.php:19-25}( )  ..\Route.php:387
```

I have tried absolutely everything but to no avail. I also tried getting headers directly with:

```
$device_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_ID'];
```

but this also failed. Any ideas how I can get a header?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's because of your PHP version / Slim version. This is my `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "2.3.*"
}
```

I'm using PHP 5.5.14 on Mac OSX Yosemite. But anyway, try this:

```
// closure callback
function getProject($id)
{
    // connect to database and return project details
    // var_dump($id);
}

// act as a middleware, the first argument is \Slim\Route
function addAuthorize($route)
{
    // var_dump($route); // \Slim\Route

    $app = Slim::getInstance();
    $request = $app->request();

    $charset = $request->headers->get('ACCEPT_CHARSET');
}

$app->get('/project/:id', 'addAuthorize', 'getProject');

// Turn on the light
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do the following and not wrap things in a closure:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/project/:id', add_authorize(), 'getProject');
$app->run();
function getProject($project_title) {
    //connect to database and return project details
}

function add_authorize() use ($app) {
    $charset = $app->request->headers->get('ACCEPT_CHARSET');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get HTTP Headers like this

```
$app->request->headers->get('ACCEPT_CHARSET');
```

And that works after Slim version 2.x. You probably have a previous version, like 1.x.

The previous way to access the HTTP Headers was like this, without the getter:

```
$app->request->headers('ACCEPT_CHARSET');
```

You could simply change that in your code or move onto a new version of Slim.

In example here's the Slim Documentation for version 1.6.7
https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/1.6.7/docs/request-headers.markdown